cmake giving CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH as parameter does not work?
I have this short example CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(test LANGUAGES CXX)
include(CheckLanguage)
check_language(CUDA)
if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
        message("found")
else()
        message("not found")
endif()

Now I run this as follows
cmake . --fresh -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for a CUDA compiler
-- Looking for a CUDA compiler - NOTFOUND
not found
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)

I can also run it as follows here
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
cmake . --fresh
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for a CUDA compiler
-- Looking for a CUDA compiler - /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
found
-- Configuring done (2.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)

Now I am confused. It only works when I have the environment variable set. I expected it to work both ways, that is setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH either via the environment variable or via parameter to cmake?

While CMake describes CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH as both CMake variable and as environment one, they are separate variables: the CMake variable is not automatically set to the environment one and vice versa.
It is true that both variables affect in a similar way for find_* family of commands. And it is logical to assume that CMake searches a compiler with find_path.
However, check_language function is somehow specific: it actually creates a new process: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CheckLanguage.cmake#L118
In that process CMake tries to configure a (new) project with regular project() command used for activate the requested language.
Environment variables are automatically passed to the new process. However, CMake variables from the parent process are NOT passed to subprocess automatically. Exactly this constitutes the difference in behaviors you observe.
